# Angular js 1 local video player

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video, video-streaming

I have a feature where I can upload videos to the system. It works fine but I am having trouble playing the video, I can't find a library or a player to use. Anyone can recommend an angular js video player ? or a directive we can use. Thank you. iframe does not work because we know it uses the built-in player from the website we embed. There is no issue regarding uploading the videos, the issue is on what video player library we can use.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try to use this library [video.js](https://videojs.com/).

Comment: What is your problem using standard html5 video player?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will play a video using the standard browser HTML5 video player - this is old, original Angular 1, as I think you ask.

```js
// function called when user clicks the play button for a particular video
    function playVideo(video) {
        console.log("playVideo button clicked"); 
        // set the video player window to the player window instead of blank
        $scope.playerWindowURL = './templates/video_player_window.html';
        $scope.collabServerPlayVideoURL = colabConfig.colabServerBaseURL + "/uploaded_videos/" + video.file_name;
    };
```

```html
<div>
    <!-- HTML5 video tag to play video -->
    <video width="320" height="180" autoplay controls="true" src="{{collabServerPlayVideoURL}}"></video>
</div>
```

Full repository is here in case you want to see it - it not maintained but worked last time I checked a couple of years ago: https://github.com/mickod/ColabServer

Comment: how about for pause and play?

Comment: @Mr.RajivKumar - the standard pause play etc controls will be present because of the 'control="true"' attribute.